# Acessing request body without using Express Nodejs

Tags: node.js, httprequest

So I am trying to access the body of a request I am sending. I don't want to incorporate Express for this project. I understand that I essentially have to stream the body in from the incoming request, however it seems that my approach isn't pulling any data from the request. Here is what I have

**The request**

```
var query = document.getElementById('search').value;
      console.log(query);
      axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: url,
        headers: {},
        data: {
          query: query
        }
      }).then((response) => {
        if(response.status == 200){
          console.log(response);
          this.tweet = response;
        }
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

**Where I am handling the request**

```
http.createServer((req, res ) => {
    //Setting CORS Headers
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Request-Method', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    if ( req.method === 'OPTIONS' ) {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end();
        return;
    }
    else if(req.url == "/search"){
        let body = 'Our Data: ';
        req.on('data', chunk => {
            body += chunk.toString();
        });
        req.on('end', () => {
            console.log(body);
        });
        //console.log(data);
        callTweetAPI.callTweetAPI(function(response) {
            res.write(JSON.stringify(response));
            res.end();
        });
    }
}).listen(port);
```

The output I expect would be the data I sent in the axios request so 'query', but I end up with blank output. It seems that the request being sent through doesn't have a data block available?

Comment: You are using the GET method. Axios does not allow for data in GET methods, nor should it... Use POST to send data. Or use query with the params property.

Comment: Okay thank you. I think I am getting mixed up with running a get request like this "example.com/query" I changed the method to post and it works correctly